# How to make a HighCharts drilldown column/bar chart that does not hide the non-drilldown categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is the  [column drilldown](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) demo.

When a user clicks on a column, that bar appears to break down into its parts. However, all the other top level categories are now hidden.

Is there a way to keep the top level categories displayed?

Further explanation/clarification:
Suppose there are three categories: A, B & C. And each category has sub categories 1, 2 & 3. To start with, the chart would show A, B & C. Then, clicking on say A, the graph would show the categories A1, A2, A3, B & C.

Comment: is this what you need http://jsfiddle.net/AMwtV/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify click event, and instead of creating new chart (setChart()) you can use setData() function and update only series (like A serie) with new items (A1, A2, A3).

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()